# .htaccess rewrite redirect paths with exceptions

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I want to setup my htaccess like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?slash1=$1&slash2=$2&slash3=$3&slash4=$4 [NC]
```

but preserve certain directories that shouldn't be affected by above, like domain.com/banana should be going to just domain.com/banana and not index.php with slash1=banana.

Comment: You may get better answers on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Just add RewriteCond like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(banana|oranges|apple)(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?slash1=$1&slash2=$2&slash3=$3&slash4=$4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you do that with multiple exceptions? eg bana and oranges and apples..